# How to dynamically change data for progress bar in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I would like to change the data for the progress bar depending on the text that is inside the "#selectCountry" div. So, when you click on Belgium the parent ul li  text will change also, which will then update the data. (code snippet for this below)

```
$("ul#countries li a").click(function() {
  $("#selectCountry").html($(this).text())

});
```

Here is a plnk of my progress so far;

http://plnkr.co/edit/jkywRLmvLcOUkQhP0WDf?p=preview

I know the part that needs to change is here

```
var divRight = dId.selectAll("#rightSkills div")
  .data(progressData);
```

From what I've read, when updating data inside d3.js you should create a new function specifically for that purpose, but as I'm not calling the data inside a function I'm not sure if this is possible without rewriting the code?

Here is all the code;

HTML;

```
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="selectCountry">Country</a>
      <ul id="countries">
        <li><a href="#">Belgium</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Netherlands</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="skills">
    <div id='rightSkills'> </div>
  </div>
```

and jQuery/D3;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadChart();

  console.log(progressData)
});

$("ul#countries li a").click(function() {
  $("#selectCountry").html($(this).text())

});

//Data for right div
var progressData = [{
  "skill": "AngularJS",
  "progress": 60
}];

var progressData2 = [{
  "skill": "AngularJS",
  "progress": 32
}];



var dId = d3.select("#rightSkills");

//Bind data for right bars
var divRight = dId.selectAll("#rightSkills div")
  .data(progressData);

//Add shadow for the right bars
divRight.enter().append("div")
  .attr("class", "shadow");

//Create the bars
d3.select("body").selectAll(".shadow")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "bar");

//Create the path
d3.select("body").selectAll(".bar")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "path");

//Add the pattern for the bars
d3.select("body").selectAll(".path")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "pattern");

//Animate the bars when they are both visible on screen
function loadChart() {

  var start_val = 0;

  //add the percentage to the progress bar and transition the number
  d3.select("body").selectAll(".pattern")
    .append("div")
    .text(start_val)
    .attr("class", "percentage")
    .transition()
    .delay(function(d, i) {
      return 200;
    })
    .duration(1000)
    .style("min-width", function(d, i) {
      return (d.progress * 3) / 2 + "px";
      console.log(1);
    })
    .tween(".percentage", function(d) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(this.textContent, d.progress),
        prec = (d.progress + "").split("."),
        round = (prec.length > 1) ? Math.pow(10, prec[1].length) : 1;

      return function(t) {
        this.textContent = Math.round(i(t) * round) / round + "%";
      };
    });

  //transition the width of the path
  d3.select("body").selectAll(".path")
    .transition()
    .delay(function(d, i) {
      return 200;
    })
    .duration(1000)
    .style("width", function(d, i) {
      return d.progress * 3 + "px";
    });
}
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: What do you mean by depending on the text that is inside a div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the result: http://plnkr.co/edit/E3ZqfT7gaB3iBVtbSMzE?p=preview

I've made your update function from your existing code like this:

```
function update(){
  d3.selectAll(".shadow").remove();
  console.log(progressData)


    //Bind data for right bars
  var divRight = dId.selectAll("#rightSkills div")
    .data(progressData);

  //Add shadow for the right bars
  divRight.enter().append("div")
    .attr("class", "shadow");

  //Create the bars
  d3.select("body").selectAll(".shadow")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "bar");

  //Create the path
  d3.select("body").selectAll(".bar")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "path");

  //Add the pattern for the bars
  d3.select("body").selectAll(".path")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "pattern");
    loadChart();
}
```

And since I didn't know what the progress should be I made it up like this:

```
$("ul#countries li a").click(function() {
  $("#selectCountry").html($(this).text());
  if($(this).text() == "Belgium"){
    progressData[0].progress = 60;
    update();
  }else if($(this).text() == "France"){
    progressData[0].progress = 80;
    update();
  }else if($(this).text() == "Netherlands"){
    progressData[0].progress = 90;
    update();
  }
```